# Buffering polygons depending on raster values

Tags: arcpy, r

I have many polygons representing mountain lakes. I need information about the slope of surrounding mountainsides in order to estimate the chance of avalanches or rockfalls into the lakes. (Btw: I'm relatively new to Python but need to do this for thousands of lakes so I think I will have to use `ArcPy`.)

My plan is to create a `buffer` around every lake for which I then can extract the slope values from my raster. But I only need those parts of a buffer that lay above the surface elevation of the lake (and can therefore be the origin of something falling into the lake).

My workflow would be to create the buffer, extract the values from the slope raster and set every pixel to `NA` where the value in the underlying DEM falls under the surface height of the lake.

Is this a valid plan or is there some `ArcPy`-package that could help me?
EDIT: It would also be possible to work with R.

Comment: I don't see much of a question here - have you tried doing what you suggest? Looks like a standard set of operations without much difficulty.

Comment: So far, I'm still preparing data. I just wanted to check beforehand if there is a package that has additional parameters to buffer creation and would save me some time.